# What type of bin is this file?

Tags: binary-analysis

Can someone help me what type of BIN file is that and can i read what is inside ? Thanks
https://easyupload.io/673djh

Comment: its firmware for laser jammer

Answer (score 2):

The file's signature is:

```
55 66 49 13 31 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00             UfI.1...........
```

Although it needs to be verified, it could indicate [Universal Flashing Interface](https://www.ufi-box.com/) firmware format.